# Android user feedback library that connects to Jira/Redmine

Tags: android, jira, redmine, crash-reports, user-feedback

Are there any libraries for Android that include:
- user feedback
- crash reports
- integration into bug trackers like Jira/Redmine...

I know about this one:
https://connect.atlassian.net/browse/ANDROID
however it seems this library is still in alpha stage, so I am looking for something more production-ready.

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 -4 Commercial crash reporting tools with Jira integration:

1. [Crashlytics](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1920&bih=936&q=crashlytics&spell=1&sa=X&ei=nS6aUdjYBZLy0gX4x4HQCw&ved=0CCsQvwUoAA)
2. [Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/%E2%80%8E)
3. [BugSense (I use this one)](http://www.bugsense.com/)

Comment: thanks for your suggestions! however unfortunately these tools do crash reports only and don't include user feedback (like jira connect). perfect would be a single service for crash reports and user feedback with jira integration and cloud testing. however unfortuntely it seems currently there is no such service for android.